# How to change a local network name from (e.g. en0) to the actual network name

Tags: swift, xcode, networking

I am creating an app where I need the name of the local network that I am currently using. When I coded this, it printed `en0` instead of the actual name.

I've tried several different things. Some print nothing, some print `en0`.

Optional error message: no network found

expected: network name

Comment: Do you mean WiFi SSID ? For macOS https://stackoverflow.com/a/34534324/2303865

Comment: Please check this answer regarding the local network. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57123033/5933733

Comment: Can you provide some code? There's actually several types of distinct networking naming in this environment.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library) should solve your problem. Also when asking a question like that, you need to show some code and explain you question in a precise and detailed manner.